# Grails - how to remove log4j from WAR

Tags: grails, ivy

I'd like to remove log4j from WAR built by Grails. My jboss has it already deployed. 
I was trying:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    ...
    dependencies {
        provided 'log4j:log4j:1.2.16'
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. After a build the WAR still contains log4j-1.2.16.jar. What to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this in bottom of **BuildConfig.groovy**:

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir ->
   delete(file:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar")
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for a quick answer. Of course it worked. +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

Whenver I do grails war, it is waste to let run grails doc as well as include grail log4j plugin into my war. The former has error and also takes significant time slowing down war generation. The latter causes a run time exception asking to put log4j.xml in grails-app/conf. Obviously the production war does not have grails-app/conf directory. Neither does it exists in tomcat bin where I run the startup from. Is there a way to avoid 'grails doc' during war and also copy a redundant file for log4j.xml to avoid that exception? My grails version is 1.3.4